# Simple file server I can put in an electricity cabinet?

Tags: hardware-rec, file-server

I'm building a new house and would like to put a file server in the electricity cabinet. The constraints this puts on the file server are small form factor and being able to work inside a closet.

Any suggestions?

Comment: From the FAQ: "Server Fault is for system administrators and desktop support professionals[..] and is not about[..] running servers at home for personal use"

Comment: This is very, very close to being a shopping recommendation and this off topic according to Super User's FAQ.

Comment: What do you want the server to do - this will dictate its CPU, memory and disk requirements which will help assess what will fill the need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked the Western Digital NAS drives? http://reviews.cnet.com/external-hard-drives/western-digital-mybook-world/4505-3190_7-32401221.html

If that's a bit too simple for what you're looking for there's some minilinux servers the size of a cigarette box to which you can plug a USB drive.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have two options:

1. Buy a Home NAS like [this](http://www.qnap.com/pro_detail_feature.asp?p_id=122), with low consumption.
2. Use a standard PC (after testing ambient and hardware temperatures)